# need help to understand the working of recursion in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#int add(int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter an positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Sum = %d",add(n));
    return 0;
}

int add(int n)
{
    if(n!=0)
    return n+add(n-1);  /* recursive call */
}
```

How will this code executed without having a base case like `if(n==0){return 0;}`?

Comment: Why is the function type set with a `#` in front?

Comment: SORRY THAT WAS A MISTAKE

Answer (score 2):

Without a base case you are creating code with undefined behaviour. Your compiler will issue a warning saying that your function that returns `int` does not have a return statement. This does not mean that the function that called it won't look for a returned value which may or may not contain garbage.

Comment: That is because of luck, not because of design.

Comment: @BOB: "Undefined behaviour" means "anything can happen". "Working fine" is "anything", as is "working fine on days with a full moon and emailing your passwords to Romania on days with a new moon".

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run into problems here: `add` will only return a value if `n != 0`, so if `n <= 0`, you won't have a value returned, so when `add` calls itself with `n-1` passed in, you'll eventually reach your base case that doesn't exist, and bad things will happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(n==0){return 0;}
```

is the base case. The base case exists to get the recursion to stop. Without a base case you will just infinitely recurse until you possibly hit some kind of error. In your case it will start adding negative numbers.

Comment: That's because you have if(n!=0) which causes the recursion to stop if n is 0. The only difference is you aren't specifying a return value so it has undefined behavior. In your case it works, but it's not guaranteed to work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644860/function-returns-value-without-return-statement

Answer (score 0):

From the C standards:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no
>   value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning
>   function.

Your compiler may warn you:

> not all control paths return a value

It's the same situation with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015797/confused-about-the-function-return-value/23017449#23017449).
This is calling convention and architecture dependent. The return value is the result of last expression evaluation, stored in the eax register. So when `n==0`, you function `add()` returns 0, but it's a result of undefined behavior.